# Storing names from text files(fgetc) and using them in an array

Tags: c, scanf

I need help, badly. I want a 2d array( where first dimension is the position of the word, and the second one is word itself) and i also have a temp array in which words are temporary stored whilst fgetc reads a textdocument where there are words written in lines(without spaces) and maximum lenght  of the name is 499

this is what i created

```
char Temp[500];
char Potential[20][500];
char FileName[100];

printf("Insert the name of the textFile you want to read from: ");
scanf("%s", FileName);

FILE *file = fopen(FileName,"r");
for(int i = 0; fgets(Temp, 500, file) != EOF; i++ ){
    Potential[i] = Temp;
}
```

I'm obviously doing something very wrong, but i don't know what

---Edited--- Full Code

```
int main(){

    char Temp[500];
    char Potential[20][500];
    char FileName[100];

    printf("Insert textfile Name: ");
    scanf("%s", FileName);

    FILE *file = fopen(FileName,"r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("error!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int counter;
    char c;
    while (1) {
        if ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            Potential[counter][0] = c;
        }
        else { break;}

        fscanf(file, "%s\n", &Potential[counter][1]);
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++){   //i used this to check if it saved, but it really hasnt 
       printf("%s ", Potential[i][0]);  //came to this
    }

}
```

----- Textfile

```
clarkson
bender
Pony
BB
Sonic
dudewhat
```

Comment: `Potential[i] = Temp` does not copy the data in Temp.  Use `strcpy`

Comment: change `char c = 0;` to `int c;` for a start. second: terminate the string if you get out of the loop. (EOF != 0) third:`if (c = fgetc(file) != EOF) {` should be `if ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {`

Comment: Tried changing it, still nothing

Comment: In for loop: fgets or fgetc ?